# Modal Form in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

suppose I have a link in my project that open a modal contains register form and this form be validate by angular,
I used `ng-bootstrap` library in my project and in modal I defined a directive and then write a component for it but the modal won't be opened and an error occured :

```
ERROR Error: No provider for Router!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9562)
    at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10644)
    at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11147)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:11011)
```

**app.component.html :**

```
    <ng-template #signup let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6"></div>
                <div class="col-5 mt-5 mb-2">
                    <div class="wrapper-left-content">
                        <app-register-form></app-register-form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

**register.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup,  Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.services';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register-form',
    templateUrl: '../templates/register.component.html'
})
@Injectable()
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    private errorMessage: any ;
    closeResult: string;

    FirstName = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
    ]);
    LastName = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
    ]);

    Password = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6)
    ]);
    Password_Confirm = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
    ]);
```

How can I solved it ?

**I invoke modal by this code :**

```
<div class="user-info">
    <div class="user-login-link">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup" (click)="open(signup)"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="user-login-link">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signin" (click)="open(signin)"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to show / hide using Angular's `*ngIf` directive ?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with modals or ng-bootstrap. You seem to be using the Router service somewhere (where), but haven't imported the RouterModule in your root NgModule.

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: What does your app.module look like? As said previously, it appears that your missing the RouterModule in your NgModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No provider for Router` means you are missing this definition:

```
//For the app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(...)]

//For other modules
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(...)],
```

Also make sure you are using its latest version. I mean the 3rd party component.
There are other good components such as https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap that you can try too.

Comment: I'm down-voting since your answer is misleading: the question is about https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal which has _nothing_ to do with  `ngx-bootstrap` - those are 2 separate projects and in no case a rename! Please remove the wrong info info and I can remove down-vote.